# Ubuntu14.04 install glib-2.50.0

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, glib

I'm trying to install glib-2.50.0 on Ubuntu 14.04. When I ran

```
./configure
```

in terminal. It came out with

```
configure: error: *** Could not find libmount
```

How to solve it?

Comment: Install `łibmount-dev`.

Answer (score 5):

You need to install libmount, which can be done via apt package manager

```
sudo apt install libmount-dev
```